# How to save the output into a file

Tags: java

In a program, I currently have

```
process.serialize(System.out);
```

This generally output the object "process" to the screen in a XML format.

But I want to redirect this XML format into a saved file, like test.XML. How to do that in java? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` is a of `PrintStream` type so you should have a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). 
Using [`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream%28java.io.File%29) combined with a [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) like this:

```
process.serialize(new PrintStream(new File("my file")));
```

will do the work.

Comment: thanks. By the way, do I have to close this newly created file as what we need in C. If it is required, how to do that in Java?

Comment: @user288609, I believe it's best practice to always explicitly close streams (and resources of any kind) by yourself. This way you control when it happens, and minimize the amount of time the resource was busy.

Answer (score 2):

this specifically goes like

```
process.serialize(new PrintStream("test.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answers by equality and ratchet freak, and I'd like to add a few points:

- You can learn more about different ways to work with streams and files from Sun/Oracle's [tutorial on I/O](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html).
- It's important to close every stream you use, by calling the stream's `close()` method. Placing those calls in a `finally` block will ensure that all the resources are released regardless of any encountered exceptions.